# SiteCore Xpress and Cassini

Tags: sitecore, cassini

Has anyone successfully set up SiteCore Express with Cassini?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore works like a charm with Cassini but officially we'renot supporting it yet.
We're in process of reviewing the Visual Studio support. Cassini is part of it.
Have you difficulties setting it up? Please let us know!

Comment: do you have a step by step tutorial somewhere?  I am trying to install SiteCore express and stop when I see the warning asking for IIS 7.

Answer (score 0):

Hey don't know how old this question is - but I setup Sitecore Xpress with Cassini and Sqlite on an XP Home rig. Bit fiddly to get going, but works sweet!